# rosjava on Android device with local network address

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use rosjava on Android devices with 3G network connection.
But some devices obtain local IP addresses.

I think we have to use VPN or SSH tunneling for communicating other nodes.

```
http://answers.ros.org/question/2007/how-to-set-up-vpn-between-ros-machines
http://answers.ros.org/question/2124/ssh-tunnels-and-ros
```

But I think these ways are not good to force users to do.
Is there any other solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11918/rosjava-on-android-device-with-local-network-address/) by [manabu](https://answers.ros.org/users/64/manabu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most mobile service providers (at least here in germany) are using network adress translation for the mobile clients. Since ROS needs bidirectional direct connectivity between alle nodes, i would guess that there is indeed no other option than using some sort of tunneling.

Maybe you can find a solution that doesn't need ROS-Nodes directly on the mobile clients, but have a server offering some of the functionality as a webservice, which is then called by the mobile clients.

In fact i would prefer the (web-)service approach, since ROS itself provides no sort of authentication and/or authorization, so any client would be able to publish and subscribe to any topic they want...

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2011-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manabu](https://answers.ros.org/users/64/manabu/) on 2011-11-13**:
Thanks for your answer. Making a web service is a better approach, but developing web application with high transparency to ROS network is difficult for me. No authentication may become a problem in the future indeed. Tunneling seems to be a only way to use android.rosjava applications.